# How to override setImageResource correctly so that it keeps the rotation of an ImageButton?

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view class that extends ImageButton. I did so because there this new button class allowed me to do some animations.

The actual problem that I have is the following: When I click on the button, I want it to change its image drawable. However, when I set a new image like this

```
private void setCustomButtonIcon() {
    if (mEnabled) {
        myCustomButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybutton_off);
    } else {
        myCustomButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybutton_on);
    }
}
```

then the rotation that it had, since it may have been rotated during the animation, is not preserved.

Now, the obvious idea is to override `setImageResource` in my custom button class. How can I do that so that the rotation of the button is preserved?

Comment: use matrix scale type

Comment: ok, what exactly shall i do?

Comment: call getImageMatrix() and then rotate the returned matrix

Comment: it doesnt work for me. I tried this: Matrix matrix = this.getImageMatrix(); matrix.setRotate(newRotation);
        this.setImageMatrix(matrix);

Comment: did you setScaleType to matrix ?

Comment: hmm, it should work...

Comment: maybe I have to override another method and not `setImageResource'?

Comment: for sure overriding onDraw and rotaring the Canvas  would work...

Comment: no, just tried that too. I have overridden `onDraw` and called `canvas.rotate(newRotation)` and that does not achieve anything :( what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to another issue:

Most likely, you are using the Animation class for your animations. 
So you probably used the RotationAnimation superclass, did something like

```
RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(
    fromDegrees, toDegress, pivotX, pivotY);
```

and applied that animation to your custom button.

However, as it turns out, this **only** animates a bitmap representation of your button. Or, in other words, the actual button/ view does not get rotated and remains in his orientation.

Therefore, every call to `onDraw()`, like it happens when you click on the button, will "reset the look" of your button.

So, what you probably want to use is an [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html). This will animate the whole view and fix your problem with preserving the state of the object.

You can use the animator just like this, for example:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myButton, "rotation", fromDegrees, -toDegrees)
            .setDuration(animationDuration)
            .start();
```

**Note**: `ObjectAnimator` was added in API 11. So if you are targeting older versions then you should use Jake Whartons [nineoldandroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/downloads) library. (Download the `.jar` file and add it to your libs folder in you project.)